# Regex validation rule phone field

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

In my phone field I want to add some phone validation

My try:

**HTML**

```
<input type="phone" name="phone" id="phone" title="phone" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-phone':true}">
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery', // jquery Library
        'jquery/ui', // Jquery UI Library
        'jquery/validate', // Jquery Validation Library
        'mage/translate', // Magento text translate (Validation message translte as per language)
        'mage/mage'
    ], function($){
        $.validator.addMethod(
            'validate-phone', function (value) {
                return (value !== 'okey'); // Validation logic here
            }, $.mage.__('Please enter a correct format number.'));

    });
</script>
```

With this, I get the error message `"Please enter a correct format number."` juste when I enter okey in the phone field.

I want to do the same thing when user :

- keep the field empty.
- don't enter number of 10 digits.
- and don't start with 06 or 07.

My regex : `/^0(6|7)[0-9]{8}$/` I don't know how to return it.

Comment: `return yourRegEx.test(value)`

Comment: @Tushar It works also, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery', // jquery Library
        'jquery/ui', // Jquery UI Library
        'jquery/validate', // Jquery Validation Library
        'mage/translate', // ...
        'mage/mage'
    ], function($){
        $.validator.addMethod(
            'validate-phone', function (value) {
                // Test against your Regex
                return /^0(6|7)[0-9]{8}$/.test(value);
            }, $.mage.__('Please enter a correct format number.'));

    });
</script>
```

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

Side note: `+33612345678` is a valid phone number too (an alternative to `0612345678`)